# Can I use a string of '$_POST(s)' in a MYSQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have a dynamic form that is driven by the db and I have a set of columns and a set of fields that seem to align correctly but I get a syntax error when the form is submitted.
I have chosen to use the explode and implode functions to create and manipulate string values.

The number of db columns and form POST fields is always >= 1.

```
  ///array>string of Columns///
  $dbColumns=$row_task_fields['task_fields'];
  $taskColumns = explode(', ' , $dbColumns);
  $Columns = array();
  foreach($taskColumns as $columnValue) {
  $Columns[] = '`' . $columnValue . '`';
  }
  $columnList = implode(', ' , $Columns);

  ///array>string of fields///
  $Fields = array();
  foreach($taskColumns as $fieldValue) {
  $Fields[] = '$_POST["' . $fieldValue . '"]';
  }
  $fieldList=implode(', ' , $Fields);


  if($_GET['count'] == 0) {
  if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "add_task_dates")) { 
  $user=$_POST['user'];
  $admin=$_SESSION['MM_Username'];
  $p=$_SESSION['p'];

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO practice_task (task_id, user_name, practice_id, " . $columnList . ", practice_admin, `admin_comments`)
  VALUES (%s, '$user', '$p', " . $fieldList . ", '$admin', %s)",
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['task_id'], "text"),
  GetSQLValueString($_POST['comment'], "text"));
```

My main question is, will this work? Since the columns and Fields needed in the query are not static, does the query see the string(s) as one value or multiple values?

I apologize if my posting methods are unorthodox, for this is my first post.

Comment: Try `echo $insertSQL` and you'll see what it sees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop that creates `$Fields` is wrong. It should be:

```
foreach($taskColumns as $fieldValue) {
    $Fields[] = "'" . GetSQLValueString($_POST[$fieldValue], 'text') "'";
}
```

Your `$fieldList` just contains the names of the `$_POST` variables, not their values, and there were no quotes around the values.

Comment: Ah yes thank you. I have changed the code to what you showed, but still got a syntax error. I then realized that the  , 'text' type at the end of the GetSQLValueString(...) part was conflicting with some of the fields. I should of specified that some of the fields were date and time types.